# Is there any case in which removing a BOM from a Js file created in Visual Studio 2008 will cause problems?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, rhino, byte-order-mark, jasmine

I need to automate tests of our javascript files using Rhino and Jasmine.
We have a lot of js files created in visual studio, and thus contain a byte order mark...

Rhino doesn't like this and moans about the BOM...

Is there any case, no matter how fringe, that will cause the javascript to malfunction if I just strip out the BOM from the Javascript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers may dislike the BOM too. It is better to leave it out anyway and specify proper encoding when using/sending the file.